# Calculate cost of standard or express delivery

Tags: php

I've got the following code, which calculates net delivery cost to 4 decimal places.  Delivery can be either standard or express shipping.  It is intended to return a string in 4 decimal places of the cost of delivery.

I can't think of another time where I've written something like `$standardShipping = !$expressShipping` or generically `variable = !boolean`.  But it feels much more readable this way as I often find when reading `!$variable` the exclamation is easy to miss.  Any reason why I this is a bad idea? Or perhaps I should instead do `false === $variable` instead of `!$variable` ?

```
public function calculateNetDelivery4dp(bool $expressShipping = false): string
{
    $standardShipping = !$expressShipping;
    // if account has free standard delivery or free standard and express delivery and using standard delivery
    if (
        ($this->user?->getAccount()?->isFreeStandardDelivery()
            || $this->user?->getAccount()?->isFreeStandardAndExpressDelivery()
        )
        && $standardShipping
    ) {
        return '0.0000';
    }

    // if account has free express delivery and using express delivery
    if ($this->user?->getAccount()?->isFreeStandardAndExpressDelivery() && $expressShipping) {
        return '0.0000';
    }

    $basket = $this->basketService->getCurrentBasket();

    $basketItemsAllFreeStandardDelivery = true;
    foreach ($basket->getBasketItems() as $basketItem) {
        if (false === $basketItem->getProduct()->isFreeStandardDelivery()) {
            $basketItemsAllFreeStandardDelivery = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($basketItemsAllFreeStandardDelivery && $standardShipping) {
        return '0.0000';
    }

    if ($standardShipping) {
        return '4.1600';
    }

    return '6.6600';
}
```

Comment: Define a $ZERO constant and return that in several places. (Or define a helper so you can `return format(0)`.) Your boolean quandary stems from wanting to give names to both the positive and negative cases. We have a technical solution for that. Define enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't bother declaring the inverse boolean variable `$standardShipping`.  If you like seeing the explicit variable, that's fine too.

I don't think I support the idea of returning float values as strings.  For a method that "calculates" a price, I wouldn't expect the return value to be any kind of formatted string.  String formatting is a responsibility for another method in your application.

Perhaps it would be helpful for you to define some class level constants for `STANDARD_SHIPPING_COST` and `EXPRESS_SHIPPING_COST`.

If you don't like the bloat of the "whole basket" loop in your method, you can pull that out into a new private method.

New code:

```
public function calculateNetDelivery4dp(bool $expressShipping = false): float
{
    // handle unrestricted free shipping
    if ($this->user?->getAccount()?->isFreeStandardAndExpressDelivery()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // handle express shipping
    if ($expressShipping) {
        return self::EXPRESS_SHIPPING_COST;
    }

    // handle standard shipping
    if (
        $this->user?->getAccount()?->isFreeStandardDelivery()
        || $this->hasFreeStandardDeliveryForWholeBasket()
    ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return self::STANDARD_SHIPPING_COST;
}

private function hasFreeStandardDeliveryForWholeBasket(): bool
{
    foreach ($this->basketService->getCurrentBasket()->getBasketItems() as $basketItem) {
        if (false === $basketItem->getProduct()->isFreeStandardDelivery()) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your wise words!  The reason for returning a string is because of the imprecision of float.  There has been issues with rounding float.  In other calculations, I'm using `bcmath` operations, which returns a string https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php